# Is the ELMER form design guidelines still current? Any other good government guidelines out there?

Tags: forms, guidelines, standards, government

I came across the [ELMER](http://www.elmer.no/english/) form design guidelines published by the Norwegian Ministry of Trade and Industry, which gives a pretty comprehensive and reasonably well documented set of guidelines for the design of forms on government websites, which I guess can be generalized to public transaction workflows. However, I don't know if the published date of 2006 means that some of the concepts and ideas are a little bit out of date, especially in reference to mobile device design patterns.

Has anyone else come across similar government standards and what are their thoughts? I suggest that there should be similar standards drafted by organizations like [UXPA](https://uxpa.org/) to set a baseline standard so we don't have to keep debating certain questions here.

Comment: There's *always* room for debate in UX. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*U.S. Department of Health and Human Services* has created and maintains a wonderful website: http://www.usability.gov. It contains a wealth of **UX resources** of various types, including the ones from a *government organization perspective* (see section **"Guidance and Government-specific Resources"** at http://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/index.html). Hope it helps.

**UPDATE:**

Information applicable to forms, is somewhat scattered across usability.gov site. However, in my opinion, some **relevant sections** are the following:

- **Information related to OMB forms** - US-specific, but may be used for other countries as well (http://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/guidance/pra-overview.html);
- **Various sections** across the *Research-Based Web Design and Usability Guidelines*, as applicable to forms design (http://guidelines.usability.gov);
- **Documents within the "Forms" category** (http://guidelines.usability.gov/search/results?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=&categories=Forms&x=37&y=26).

In addition to usability.gov site, the following **non-US resources** may be useful:

- **Web Guide by Australian Government** (http://webguide.gov.au), including the section on forms (http://webguide.gov.au/required-information/online-forms);
- **Report** *"Improving and reviewing government forms: A practical guide"* by **UK's National Audit Office** (www.governmentontheweb.org/sites/governmentontheweb.org/files/ImprovingReviewingGovernmentForms.pdf)
- **Report** *"Difficult forms: How government agencies interact with citizens"* by **UK's National Audit Office** (http://www.governmentontheweb.org/sites/governmentontheweb.org/files/Difficult_Forms.pdf), for citation, see: http://www.governmentontheweb.org/publications/24.

Comment: That's right, I almost forgot about that one. Although I think it would be good if they provided more examples to go with the guidelines, as the ELMER guide does.

Comment: @MichaelLai: Usability.gov has a **much wider scope** in terms of *coverage* of various UX aspects (dimensions). Feel free to upvote, if you find my answer valuable :-).

Comment: Can you provide the reference to the specific section about forms in your answer, just for those that want to reference the answer quickly? Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelLai: Updated the answer per your request.